# Recommend where to get screenplay edited?

Tags: screenwriting

I assume this is the next step in the process when I get through with this 3rd draft in format. Online or in person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bunch online editors and proofreaders. I can't provide you links because I don't want to spam.
Just google - online proofreading and you will definitely find one